# What does the ${applicationName} in flutter AndroidManifest.xml means?

Tags: android, flutter, manifest

The `AndroidManifext.xml` has this code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.skeleton">
   <application
        android:label="skeleton"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

On what real value the `applicationName` is interpolated?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This value is set by the Flutter Gradle plugin.

It can have 2 value :

If you have multidex enabled and your app has a minSdk less than 20, this  value will be `io.flutter.app.FlutterMultiDexApplication`.

Else, it will be `android.app.Application`.

You can override this value by setting the `base-application-name` property (in the gradle.properties of your android folder for example).

Source -
[flutter.gradle](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle#L261)
[flutter.gradle.kts](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle.kts)

Remember that you can always inspect the resulting APK (in `build/app/outputs/flutter-apk`) to see what value is in the final Manifest. Or you can just read the merged manifest in `build/app/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Could you let me know how to set the base-application-name property in gradle.properties? There is no documentations i could find related to it.

Comment: Your second link is outdated.